# TextView cause an error on android emulator

Tags: android

I create TextView and set it to show value of some variable. The problem occur when I run android emulator, the application start normally, but when I click on the screen to let TextView show on screen, it's error.

This is LogCat of this application.

```
03-20 11:38:02.871: D/dalvikvm(3662): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 86K, 5% free 3047K/3200K, paused 55ms, total 57ms
03-20 11:38:02.901: I/dalvikvm-heap(3662): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.930MB for 1987216-byte allocation
03-20 11:38:02.951: D/dalvikvm(3662): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 4985K/5144K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
03-20 11:38:03.981: I/Choreographer(3662): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-20 11:38:04.031: D/gralloc_goldfish(3662): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-20 11:38:16.111: I/Choreographer(3662): Skipped 345 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-20 11:38:22.541: W/ResourceType(3662): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
03-20 11:38:22.551: D/AndroidRuntime(3662): Shutting down VM
03-20 11:38:22.551: W/dalvikvm(3662): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1af5ba8)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662): Process: com.example.yyy, PID: 3662
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at com.example.yyy.Find2Activity.onClick(Find2Activity.java:167)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-20 11:38:22.601: E/AndroidRuntime(3662):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 11:38:27.071: I/Process(3662): Sending signal. PID: 3662 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you add some code here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

The stacktrace is telling you  that you are calling `yourTextView.setText(1);`, with `1`
as int value. Change it to  `yourTextView.setText(""+1);` to convert that value to String.

If you pass a int to `setText` android will try to look up for a String with `id` the `int` you provided

Comment: I can fix it with your solution. Thanks :)